# AppStore - Application runtime Validation ( Sign key in google )

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, app-store, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

lastly we receive a lot of cracked installs without jailbroken devices. The problem is enterprise distribution. Since a week I'm searching for one good solution, but I can't find any... The main problem is, it's a multiplayer based game so any hacks are destroying our game community.

I must say I'm desperate as it's really easy to crack the game with **Rasticrac** for example ( we did it in an hour). But we couldn't find any way to validate on the server if a client is running **our legal** app downloaded from AppStore or the one installed from the crack.

It's pretty easy on Google as we have SSL connection where we send encrypted Sign key, we decrypt it on server-side and compare to original sign key. If someone is using a modded version, the signing key is different.

We wanted to introduce the same verification on iOS... But we found that it's impossible to do...

Please help us, we strongly searching for a good solution, as we need it in our new productions as well.

Comment: Every App has a certificate in the actual data, I wonder if theres a way to detect if that certificate is from Apple, or from Your server/company/appId, or a cracked certificate.

Have an upvote because Im really curious about this

Comment: My Reccomendation: This will take time, but try adding a "Player State Authentication". Everywhere your player is at, depending on Movement, location, everything, use Game States (it could be a simple variable sent to the server) and make sure its "Authentic Movements and Player Data" else, just ban their UUID.

Similarly, you can track every variable, like Weapon Damage, Current Weapon, and have them all as serversided variables, so if they change, BAN HAMMER